# Why does my JSON request fail more than 50% of the time?

Tags: json, swift

I am making a spelling bee game that gets words from Oxford Dictionary's API. The app delivers words expected, but its failure rate is higher than I want. I'm getting about a 25 to 36 percent success rate; most words deliver a nil result but that's obviously my fault, not the API's. I want a higher success rate because the API is not free. Or is this kind of hit-rate typical for major APIs?

**I know that I need to change this over to Swift 4's Decodable for JSON** but I haven't gotten around to figuring that one out yet.

Can you find anything in my code that would cause perfectly simple words to be skipped, such as one-syllable words that would be in any dictionary? At the end of the code, I've tacked on a sample console log of the words that succeed and fail.

```
func speakRandomWord() {
 //Now that a valid random word is selected, this where I make my API call.


   appId = "private"
   appKey = "private"
   language = "en"
   word = randomWord //I get the random word from Lexicontext, Oxford API doesn't support random words yet. I filter out entriest that aren't one word.
   regions = "gb"
   word_id = word.lowercased() 
   url = URL(string:"https://odapi.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/\(language)/\(word_id)/regions=\(regions)")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(appId, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_id")
    request.addValue(appKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "app_key")

    let session = URLSession.shared
    print ("URLSession began...")
    dataAttempted += 1
    _ = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
    print("statusCode: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

    if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {

        print ("URLSession failed, trying again...")
        self.urlSessionFailed += 1
        self.selectRandomWord()
        self.speakRandomWord()
        }

   }

   DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
   self.activitySpinner.stopAnimating()
   self.activitySpinner.isHidden = true
   self.theUserInput.becomeFirstResponder()
   self.repeatButton.isEnabled = true
   self.defineButton.isEnabled = true


}

    if let response = response,
        let data = data,
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]

        {

if
let dictionary = jsonData as? [String: Any],

let results = dictionary["results"] as? [[String: Any]],
!results.isEmpty, case var result = results[0],

let lexicalEntries = result["lexicalEntries"] as? [[String: Any]],
!lexicalEntries.isEmpty, case var lexicalEntry = lexicalEntries[0],

let derivatives = lexicalEntry["derivatives"] as? [[String:Any]],
!derivatives.isEmpty, case var derivative = derivatives[0],

let pronunciations = lexicalEntry["pronunciations"] as? [[String: Any]],
!pronunciations.isEmpty, case var pronunciation = pronunciations[0],

let entries = lexicalEntry["entries"] as? [[String:Any]],
!entries.isEmpty, case var entry = entries[0],

    let senses = entry["senses"] as? [[String:Any]],
    !senses.isEmpty, case var sense = senses[0],

    let examples = sense["examples"] as? [[String:Any]],
    !examples.isEmpty, case var example = examples[0] 

//Now I pick out details from the JSON like audio, sample sentence, etc.

 {

if let theText = example.removeValue(forKey:"text") {

self.theText = String(describing:theText)
 print ("The value is \(self.theText)")

}


if let meaning = sense.removeValue(forKey:"short_definitions") {

self.newMeaning = String(describing:meaning)
print ("The short meaning is \(self.meaning)")

}


if let origin = entry.removeValue(forKey:"etymologies") {



    self.newEtymology = String(describing:origin)

    self.decoded2 = String(self.newEtymology.characters.filter({!"U0123456789".contains(String($0))}))

   // print ("The etymology is \(self.decoded2)")

            }

if let audioPath = pronunciation.removeValue(forKey:"audioFile") {
    print ("MP3 audio file for \(self.word) exists")
    print (audioPath)
    self.audioPaths.append(audioPath as! String)
    self.dataIsValid += 1
    self.successfulWords.append(self.word)


   self.path = String(describing:audioPath)
    self.repeatPath = self.path
    print (self.path)
   if let url = URL.init(string: self.path) {
    self.player = AVPlayer.init(url: url)
   self.player.play()
    }


}

else {
    print ("No audio data for \(self.word)!")
    self.dataFailed += 1
    self.audioFailed.append(self.word)
    self.selectRandomWord()


   }

}
    else {
    print ("\(self.randomWord) failed, reason unknown!")
    self.dataFailed += 1
    self.failedOtherReason.append(self.word)
    self.selectRandomWord()

       }
    }


}).resume()

}

 // Console results:
 //URL Session failures: 5
 //API attempts: 41.0
 //API successes: 15.0
 //API failures: 21.0
 //Successful Oxford API hit percentage: 36.5853658536585

 //These 15 words succeeded: ["denunciation", "strategic", "strategic",  "detract", "opaline", "opaline", "jurist", "exit", "throaty", "mother", "mother", "regroup", "early", "managerial", "recalcitrant"]

  //These 0 words had no audio: []

  //These words 21 words failed for an unknown reason: ["overlook", "lignin", "mandate", "evident", "anagrammatize", "avoirdupois", "extraterrestrial", "opaline", "cauterization", "malted", "clear", "snuggle", "fresno", "jurist", "streamline", "nonconforming", "trochee", "adventitia", "rudiment", "sculpturesque", "bicycle"]
```

Comment: Unrelated but `var result = results.first { ...` is much more efficient than `!results.isEmpty, case var result = results[0] { ...`

Comment: Try using SwiftyJSON - much easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to debug this specific problem but it is likely that the JSON response you are receiving has optional fields. Fields that are expected to be empty for certain responses. This part of your code,

```
  if
    let dictionary = jsonData as? [String: Any],
    let results = dictionary["results"] as? [[String: Any]],
    !results.isEmpty,
    case var result = results[0],
    let lexicalEntries = result["lexicalEntries"] as? [[String: Any]],
    !lexicalEntries.isEmpty,
    case var lexicalEntry = lexicalEntries[0],
    let derivatives = lexicalEntry["derivatives"] as? [[String:Any]],
    !derivatives.isEmpty,
    case var derivative = derivatives[0],
    let pronunciations = lexicalEntry["pronunciations"] as? [[String: Any]],
    !pronunciations.isEmpty, case var pronunciation = pronunciations[0],
    let entries = lexicalEntry["entries"] as? [[String:Any]],
    !entries.isEmpty,
    case var entry = entries[0],
    let senses = entry["senses"] as? [[String:Any]],
    !senses.isEmpty, case var sense = senses[0],
    let examples = sense["examples"] as? [[String:Any]],
    !examples.isEmpty,
    case var example = examples[0]
    //Now I pick out details from the JSON like audio, sample sentence, etc.
  {
```

needs to be split to handle (and report) missing fields. That is 20 boolean tests that all must pass before your 'good' path executes. **What is likely happening is that your dictionary accesses are failing.** If for instance dictionary does not contain "lexicalEntries", then that will take the failure path and not return an empty array as you are expecting.

Confirm that the same words fail every time. Look at the actual JSON for failed words and make sure that every field is being reported.

**UPDATE:**

```
if let response = response,
  let data = data,
  let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
{
  guard let dictionary = jsonData as? [String: Any] else {
    print("Error: dictionary was not returned by endpoint")
    return
  }
  guard let results = dictionary["results"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
    print("Error: no results array returned by endpoint")
    return
  }
  result = results.first
  ...
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'm having trouble breaking up even one without getting lots of errors. Would you show me what one such set of booleans looks like when separated? Thank you!